# enforce naming conventions for page aliases by content type

Tags: 8, path-aliases

I would like to set mandatory url naming conventions for custom content type nodes.

When users create a new content type I want to force certain naming conventions for the url alias. For example:

when creating 'Type A' and 'Type B' pages they should have aliases of the form:

- www.example.com/a/{user-assigned} (Type A)
- www.example.com/b/{user-assigned} (Type B)

is there a way to do this in Drupal 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this use case is covered under the [Pathauto module](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto).

Essentially, you'll add a new *Content* patterns (from the admin UI in **admin/config/search/path/patterns**) for each of your content types with the following path pattern, `my_type/[node:author:account-name]`.

As long as the user doesn't have the *Administer URL aliases* & *Create and edit URL aliases* permissions, their created content path will be set automatically without being able to change the path.